# What code do you actually write in Uncaught Exception Handler (as in the setup suggested by Testflight)?

Tags: ios, exception, testflight

I've just run through [Testflight SDK docs](https://testflightapp.com/sdk/doc/1.2.4/) and have just collected my first crash reports - all features behave as described in documentation and it is pretty awesome.

What I don't understand is the two following handlers SDK docs suggest to set up:

```
/*
My Apps Custom uncaught exception catcher, we do special stuff here, and TestFlight takes care of the rest
*/
void HandleExceptions(NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"This is where we save the application data during a exception");
    // Save application data on crash
}
/*
My Apps Custom signal catcher, we do special stuff here, and TestFlight takes care of the rest
*/
void SignalHandler(int sig) {
   NSLog(@"This is where we save the application data during a signal");
   // Save application data on crash
}
```

*What stuff do you write there?*

To be more specific:

I've noticed that Testflight generates crash reports on its own, i.e. not using these handlers, so the first question is:

*Should I write any Testflight-related code in these handlers?*

I do understand what should code should I write to save a data which is specific to my application, I am rather interested in what else in general I can/should do inside these handlers, and so the second:

*I understand, that **NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&HandleExceptions)** implies some general code for handling some unknown/unexpected stuff - so should I add any code that will affect how exactly my app crashes?*